# How to set up Google Analytics for a website that is based on RFQ's?

Tags: google-analytics

Looking for a way to set up Google Analytics that help track an organize RFQ's my client receives through their website. I know it can't all be explained in one post (or who would want to), but I am curious if there is a way to track a customers RFQ's in GA. If anyone has any information on this it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by using GTM to [track the forms](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106716?hl=en) they use to submit these RFQs.

You can also go a step further and generate an ID for the RFQ, pass this ID to GA as a custom dimension and also track it in your CRM so later on you can analyze the closing rate from RFQ to buying. If you can provide more details on the mechanisms/processes in your RFQ, we can go into more specifics.